# Unable to connect the Lumia 520 to PC for file transfer

Tags: 8.1, lumia, file-transfer, usb

I'm unable to connect the Lumia 520 to the PC with USB. It charges the phone but doesn't show the device.

I tried to update driver but that doesn't work out either. There are no system notifications in the phone either that will help to select an option for connection.

What is the best and the easiest way to take get it connected?

Comment: Have you tried with another PC? Which version of Windows is running on the PC?

Comment: What is the version of Windows Phone??? I think OS version of Windows doesn't matter.

Comment: Does the icon for connected device icon show up in desktop Windows? Have you tried another USB-cable? Broken USB-cables can charge without allowing file transfer.

Answer (score 1):

It's very much likely that the USB cable you're trying to use is broken, or a "charge only" USB cable. Try using another different cable, and see what happens.

If the problem persists, try using another machine, just as a move to troubleshoot where the problem is. If it works with another machine, then its your computer that is having issues with your phone: Something that can be resolved by uninstalling and reinstalling the drivers. If that doesn't work, then you might need to look at refreshing/upgrading your machine's operating system.

As a counteraction to your problem, try pulling out the SD card and extracting/copying the info you want.

Comment: How does the first part of this differ from the comment that I made to the question?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have Bluetooth on your computer then you can transfer the files that way.
2. Try storing the files on OneDrive or via another cloud storage app from the phone, and then downloading them to your computer.

Comment: @Kelvinelove Have you tried reading the title of the question?